# How does Rogue from the X-Men fly?

Tags: marvel, x-men, rogue

This has been a question which has bothered me for some time, as a subset of "various types of flight" in the Marvel comics. Among the **X-Men** specifically, it's a ubiquitous ability, mostly held by females. But each type of flight has a different logical basis...

- **Storm** holds herself aloft on winds
- **Jean** uses a type of telekinetic levitation
- **ArchAngel** has his natural wings
- **Angel 2** has insectoid wings
- **Banshee** and his daughter **Siren** tend to propel themselves via the force of their sonic screams in a type of "controlled air foiling."
- While not "flight", **Kitty Pride** can maneuver through air by phasing her form and "walking" on air molecules.
- **CannonBall** produces a unidirectional "blast field" which essentially turns him into a human rocket
- **Polaris** uses a type of magnetic levitation to act on her own personal magnetic field.
- Her half-sister **Scarlet Witch** either negates gravity, or uses chaos energy to "push" herself against air.

But... how exactly does **Rogue** fly?

Yes, we know Rogue got that power, her durability and super strength permanently from Ms Marvel, who has Kree DNA, so that gives an *origin* .... but it still doesn't explain the *basis* or *physical explanation* of the power.

Even *Rogue HERSELF* isn't too clear on how *that* ability works! This was even lamp shaded somewhat nearly 30 years ago in Fox's **X-Men: The Animated Series** the first time she met Angel. You can see it here; go to the 3:00 mark:

So I was curious as to **what canon explanation, if any, was given for her flight.** I thought one might be available in an addition of the *Marvel Universe Encyclopedia,* but the 2 I found didn't offer much. Canonical information would be preferred, but theories or explanations from panels in the comics would also be helpful.

Comment: The same way all comic book characters with no wings can glide through the air: comic book handwavey magical physics whatnot.

Comment: As captain marvel is a ripoff of superman, would an explanation using  superman flight powers be acceptable? Or should we stick in universe?

Comment: Asking "How does Carol Danvers fly (pre-Binary)?" would be a lot clearer.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Dude, _that_ is In NO WAY an proper answer and **you know it!* Come on, Carrot; we're supposed to be actively discussing here, dude; don't get all negative on me now. Besides... there have been _various_ explanations for flight for comic book characters, as I pointed out in the question.

Comment: @Russhiro Was just a tongue-in-cheek joke comment, I wouldn't read too much into it, I certainly don't.

Comment: @GarretGang "Captain Marvel is a rip off of Superman?".... you lost me on that one, dude; their powers act _Way_ differently, stem from different sources and are **vastly different** in _scale,_ with Supes having _faaaaaaaaaaaaaar_ greater strength, speed, durability, power and senses and Marvel having greater overall energy output and projection.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica You make a good point. Hence me pointing out the Carol Danvers connection. 2 things, though: [a] Carol has at least _three_ distinct formats of power, so I'm not sure which would apply [b] the physics would still need to be explained, or at least postulated, regardless. So as its now _totally_ Rogue's power, I just stuck to her.

Comment: They may have intended their comment as a joke, but it's true. There's not really any difference between saying that someone flies using chaos energy, telekinesis, or "quantum mechanics," and not giving any explanation.

Comment: @Adamant Oh, I can totally understand that, and its cool. I'm just very used to Carrot offering **some form** of viable explanation before going of on its "this is comics, its makes no real world sense" bend. End of the day, his statement is correct, but _the whole reason_  we even _have_ these boards is to looks for viable, plausible, or even theoretical means to discuss some of the elements we see in sci-fi and fantasy to break down how they work. Telekinesis, sonic waves and chaos energy offer at least _some form_ of energy output and _reason_ to make flight work, even if they're fictional.

Comment: @Russhiro "Questions seeking scientific solutions or explanations are off-topic"

Comment: @Russhiro As I said, it was a joke. I can remove the comment though if it's confusing/not clear.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica "...unless related directly to a cited work of fiction." There's nothing off topic about this question.

Comment: Well, the thing is that this site isn't a discussion board in the usual sense. Outside of chat, scientific explanations (using the term loosely) and fan theories are in fact *not* on-topic. Although this question may not strictly qualify as such, I am still not sure it's all that far from such questions.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot quite possibly, but it's certainly *not* "the whole reason we even have these boards"

Comment: https://www.cbr.com/captain-marvel-carol-danvers-ability-fly/ might be useful.

Comment: Ohh Damn it ..now the Xmen intro song is stuck in my head !!!!

Comment: @NigelFds Dunj! Dun! Dun! Dun! **Dun-DUN-DUN!!!* Dun-na-na-na-NAH[NUN-NUN!] Dun-na-na-na-_NAH_[NUN-NUN!] Dun-na-na-na-NAH-nun-NUN!..... **DUN-Dun-Dun!** [DUN!] 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bPEruuo-2E


**Now the VISUALS!!!*]  Cyclops...Wolverine...Rogue...Storm! The Beast! Gambit! Jubilee! Jean Grey... Professor X...

Dun-Dun-DUN! [**Dun!**]

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica I respectfully disagree. As someone who has enjoyed the X-Men cartoons and movies for many years I am extremely interested in the answer to this specific question, but I have no idea who Carol Danvers is (or at least I didn't until reading the answer referencing her below).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I totally know you were joking, dude. It didn't seem to come across in the text, but my exaggerated exasperated tone was meant to be playfully mocking in response. Sorry :-D

Comment: I like that none of the "flying" superheroes make any sense, anyway. So why single out Rogue? For example, *ArchAngel*: yes, he has wings, but wings don't work like that. No bird of that size would be able to hover in place by flapping their wings like that, that's not how they are used. If you look at seagulls when they seem "hovering", they are actually gliding against strong winds, which is not what *ArchAngel* is doing in the YT clip. Similarly, every other superhero mention is either using "magic" or bullshit physics. Why do we focus on poor Rogue? :(

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Assuming that Rogue perfectly copied Ms. Marvel's abilities, then flight is done by "sailing along the Earth's electromagnetic field".

**Ms. Marvel Vol. 1 #2**

[image: Carol Danver's flight abilities explained]
(click to enlarge)

As CBR's [How Did Carol Danvers Gain the Ability to Fly](https://www.cbr.com/captain-marvel-carol-danvers-ability-fly/) article indicates, originally this was only possible due to her costume, which heightened her natural ability to do this sailing, but an encounter with MODOK reveals that the second blast from the psyche-magnetron transferred the flight abilities of the suit directly to her body.

**Ms. Marvel Vol. 1 #7**

[image: Carol narrating that her abilities are now part of her body]
(click to enlarge)

Comment: That costume is... something else.

Comment: Sorry, this is a good answer and I've given it a vote, but I just _have_ to quote TLC from upthread: "comic book handwavey magical physics whatnot" :)

Comment: I skimmed this comic looking for the answer but somehow missed the _"sailing along the Earth's electromagnetic field"_ quote in that panel. This does appear to be the answer +1.

Comment: FWIW it _may_ have been a product of her costume but the costume was a part of her unknowingly transforming into Ms. Marvel so it was somewhat a part of her... if that makes sense. See [this page](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-tVvoRLJ0lSM/VnfYaYsSeLI/AAAAAAAAGSw/Kshh81RkxG8/s1600-Ic42/RCO013.jpg) and the [following one](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-7GIEREi48j8/VnfYav2hLZI/AAAAAAAAGS0/roKrpibRd6k/s1600-Ic42/RCO014.jpg) from Issue 2 for more information.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Ah. Rereading the panel I quoted above, the suit just enhances a "natural ability". Anyhow, I think we've got Russhiro's question answered either way.

Comment: Aye this is the answer, was just making some comments here as I'd read that comic looking for the answer so was fresh in my mind. Just somehow I skipped over that panel!

Comment: Yeah, this pretty much **does** answer it as Carrot stated. This means its a type of "Mag-Lev" flight she is using, instinctively. I had thought [considering we've seen Ms Marvel fly in space] that it was some kind of gravity manipulation, but...live and learn. Thanks, pal!